# How do you remove a route from Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, routes, sinatra

I have some dynamically loaded plugins which register their routes when they start up, however I also need to be able to remove their routes when they are disabled. Is there a way to remove existing routes?

The API didn't have any methods I could find to remove them, and the only other way I could think to do it would be to go right to the @routes object in Sinatra::Base, but I am not sure if you can do anything to that, and if you can... is it safe to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking through the code for a few minutes I do not see any code that 'destructively' mutates the `routes` other than:

```
C:\Ruby\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\sinatra-1.3.1\lib\sinatra\base.rb:
  936        def reset!
  937          @conditions     = []
  938:         @routes         = {}
  939          @filters        = {:before => [], :after => []}
  940          @errors         = {}
```

This is a 'nuke it from orbit' approach, and presumably not what you need. Based on this investigation, I think you will need to modify the `routes` hash yourself.

For the current version of code, this looks 'safe' to me, insofar as the [`route!`](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L771) method always looks up the current array of routes and iterates them normally (there is no caching):

```
def route!(base = settings, pass_block=nil)
  if routes = base.routes[@request.request_method]
    routes.each do |pattern, keys, conditions, block|
      pass_block = process_route(pattern, keys, conditions) do |*args|
        route_eval { block[*args] }
      end
    end
  end

  # Run routes defined in superclass.
  if base.superclass.respond_to?(:routes)
    return route!(base.superclass, pass_block)
  end

  route_eval(&pass_block) if pass_block
  route_missing
end
```

The internals of Sinatra around storing routes have shifted in recent releases, so I wouldn't rely on this always working without testing with each new release. Better yet, propose a patch and see if you can get the functionality accepted incorporated into the main library.

Comment: Bit of a silly question, but how do you propose a patch on github? do you raise an issue and just detail the functionality you want, or should I take a fork, add the functionality myself and then somehow notify them that I have made the change? if this is a long winded answer just say so and I will go look online for some info on github, as I havent used it that much.

Comment: You could start with an issue. It's usually easier to just fork Sinatra, make your own changes (ensure that you have test cases and documentation), push them back to your GitHub fork, and then use the "Pull Request" feature of GitHub to request that they merge your changes. Read more [here](http://help.github.com/send-pull-requests/).

Comment: Thanks, will go take a look in more detail when I get home

Answer (score 2):

May be you condider this approach,

```
before '/the_path_you_want_to_remove' do
   redirect '/the_path_is_default_page_or_someting'
end
```

You could put this `before` action for overriding the route you want to remove, so the route is not be accessed and implemented.

If you want to enable that route again, just delete the `before` action.

Or remove the item in array disable_routes

```
before do
    disable_routes = ['/test', '/test/*', '/test*']
    redirect '/default_page' if disable_routes.include?(request.path_info)
end
```

Comment: It is a possibility but the reason I want to remove them is because I have a plugin style system, so if a plugin is unloaded I want to completely remove the routes from the system. You are right though, this is a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could prevent the route from returning anything by setting an after block.