# How can I deprecate a route in a Sinatra app?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm writing a API mock server by Sinatra, it looks like below

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class APIMockServer < Sinatra::Base

  post '/mock' do
    _body = params[:body]
    _status = params[:status] || 200
    APIMockServer.send params[:method], params[:action] do
      body _body
      status _status
    end
    'success'
  end

  run! if app_file == $0

end
```

I send a post request to `/mock`, the Sinatra App will generate a route dynamically.

```
require 'restclient'

RestClient.post(
    '127.0.0.1:4567/mock',
    {
        action: '/sayhi',
        method: 'get',
        body: 'hello world'
    }
)
```

So far it works as expected, but when I send another post request with same `action`, it doesn't take effect.

```
require 'restclient'

RestClient.post(
    '127.0.0.1:4567/mock',
    {
        action: '/sayhi',
        method: 'get',
        body: 'hello world, hello Sinatra' # the body is changing
    }
)
```

I guess because I defined two routes with same name, so the Sinatra take the first matched one to response. How can I deprecate the first one, so that the last one could take effect?

Comment: I only see one route defined here. Where is the second route showing up?

Comment: It defined by `APIMockServer.send params[:method], params[:action]`, it equals to `get('/sayhi') { 'hello world' }` in this example.

Comment: That's an odd way to do it. You may need to have a "record" mode for your server, and a "playback" you can later engage. This would avoid the conflict here. This is the model used by [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr).

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I will consider the gem your recommendation. But I will feel better if my question is resolved =)

Answer (score 1):

That is an interesting app. It's a metaprogramming API.

I think the issue is that once the route is defined, it is not being redefined.

So, perhaps you need to remove the route using something like

```
remove_method params[:method]
```

or

```
APIMockServer.remove_method params[:method], params[:action]
```

I'm not sure how Sinatra manages the defined routes, but you may want to look into that. Perhaps [How do you remove a route from Sinatra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212778/how-do-you-remove-a-route-from-sinatra) would be of some help.